# Using Prisma with Yarn v3

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I am building an app using Next.js, Next-Auth, and Prisma. I am using API Routes for backend code. Recently, I upgraded Yarn on my pc to `v3.1.1`. I then created a `.yarnrc.yml` file and set the `nodeLinker` option to `"node-modules"` to avoid converting this project to PnP just yet.
When I run the dev server to work on my application, I run into this error as it tries to compile the next-auth API Route. Weirder yet, this issue does not occur when deployed via Vercel; the function logs are just fine and it works as expected.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\htech\Desktop\code\consulting\.yarn\unplugged\@prisma-client-virtual-d7adb716b6\node_modules\.prisma\client\schema.prisma'
```

When I search for similar issues, the usual solution that arises is setting a custom output path in `schema.prisma`.
When I add a custom output path and update the imports accordingly, it just spits out some esoteric internal dependency error.

```
error - ./prisma/generated/runtime/index.js:27652:17
Module not found: Can't resolve '_http_common'
  27650 |   "../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@3.3.6/node_modules/undici/lib/node/http-parser.js"(exports2, module2) {
  27651 |     "use strict";
> 27652 |     var common = require("_http_common");
```

##### Environment

- `yarn`:`v3.1.1`
- `next`: `v12.1.0`
- `@prisma/client`:`v3.10.0`
- `prisma`:`v3.10.0`
- `next-auth`:`v4.2.1`

---

This seems to be a simple issue with where it's generating to. However, I have no idea how to go about solving this issue, short of rolling back my systemwide version of yarn. Have I ran into a bug? Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: All of the errors that I've looked at point to an issue with where Prisma is generating the client vs where Yarn is resolving imports to. I have tried custom resolutions (and I continue to try them) but they often result in `Error: ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered`.

Comment: I've just made a new branch in git and am trying to move my project to use PnP. However, when I run `yarn prisma generate`, it just doesn't do anything and proceeds to max out my memory usage. It then forces Windows to shut it down. This is really weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After having tested a number of different things, I believe I have found a solution.

#### The Problem

The problem lies in how Yarn is resolving imports. Prisma CLI generates the client (by default) to `node_modules/.prisma`. Even when `nodeLinker` is set to `node-modules`, Yarn tries to resolve this import to `.yarn/unplugged/<folder-name>`, where the generated client does not exist.

#### The Solution

In order to fix this resolution problem, we have to create a custom resolution for the `.prisma` folder. This assumes that you do not have a custom output path.

```yaml
# .yarnrc.yml

nodeLinker: node-modules

packageExtensions:
  "@prisma/client@*":
    dependencies:
      ".prisma": 'link:See "resolution" field of package.json'
```

```json
# package.json

{
  ...
  "resolutions": {
     ".prisma": "link:node-modules/.prisma"
  }
}
```

[Credit to this user on Github](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1439#issuecomment-775050033)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using yarn with pnp enabled:

1. Install `@yarnpkg/pnpify` to dev dependencies
2. Prepend `yarn pnpify` with any prisma command e.g `yarn pnpify prisma generate`
3. Consider using a [custom output path](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/setup-and-configuration/generating-prisma-client#using-a-custom-output-path) in your prisma schema